# Ajax not Writing to Database

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, database

I have an HTML form that I'm trying to read data from and write into a database. A sample of the HTML for the form is shown below:

```
<div id="form">
    <div class="container-tabby1">
        <div class="wrap-tabby1">
            <form class="tabby1-form validate-form">
                <span class="tabby1-form-title">
                    New Form
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-inputtabby validate-input bg1" data-validate="Internal Error">
                    <span class="label-inputtabby">Change Request Number</span>
                    <input id="ChangeRequestNo" class="inputtabby" type="text" name="ChangeRequestNo" onload="onLoad" readonly>
                </div>


              <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                    <input id="submitRequest" type="button" class="contacttabby-form-btn" value="Submit Request" onclick="SaveChangeRequest()"/>

                </div>
```

The ajax used to write this to the database is as follows:

```
function SaveChangeRequest() {
        var o = form.getData();
        var errorMsg = "";

msg = mini.loading("Submit...");
        var jsonform = mini.encode(o);
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: urlCR,
            type: "post",
            data: { CR: jsonCR },
            cache: false,
            success: function (text) {
                debugger;
                if (text != null && text != '') {
                    mini.hideMessageBox(msg);
                    onOk();
                }
                else {
                    jAlert("Submit failed", "Error Message");
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                mini.hideMessageBox(msg);
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        })
```

Every time I attempt to submit to the database I get the "Submit failed" error message. I have another form as shown below that works perfectly fine:

```
<div id="form" style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;">
    <table width="100%;" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td width="100px;"><label>Applicant:</label></td>
            <td width="300px;"><input id="ApplicantEmail" name="ApplicantEmail" class="mini-textbox" allowinput="false" style="width: 290px;" /></td>

<td align="center">
                    <input type="button" class="searchsubmit" value="Submit" onclick="SaveForm()" style="width:120px;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        mini.parse();
        SecurityLog_PageLoad();

        var urlPersonInfo = "data/AjaxSecurityService.aspx?method=Sec_CurUserLoginInfo";
        var urlFormGetItem = "Data/ajaxservice.aspx?method=CSC_Form_GetWholeFormo&FormID=";
        var urlFormUpdateWithNotice = "Data/ajaxService.aspx?method=CSC_Form_UpdateChanges";

        var form = new mini.Form("#form");
        var searchGrid = mini.get("dgSearchResult");
        var applyGrid = mini.get("dgApplyResult")

function SaveForm() {
            var o = form.getData();
            form.validate();
            if (form.isValid() == false) return;
            var errMsg = '';
            if (o.RequestComments == null || o.RequestComments == '')
                errMsg=".Justification is empty.\n";
            if (applyGrid.data.length < 1) 
                errMsg+= ".At least apply one report before you submit.\n";
            if (errMsg != '')
            {
                jAlert(errMsg, "Validate Error");
                return;
            }
$.ajax({
                url: urlFormUpdateWithNotice,
                type: "post",
                data: { dataForm: jsonClaim, dataList: jsonList },
                cache: false,
                success: function (text) {
                    var impactID = mini.decode(text);
                    if (impactID != null && impactID != "") {
                        SecurityLog_Submit('Submit',impactID);
                        CloseWindow("ok");
                    };
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    mini.hideMessageBox(msg);
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });

</script>
```

Why does the latter form work while the first form does not?

Comment: Check it with your backend .... if you sending correct data and valid data

Comment: Check indeed what is send, check in your console your network tab when sending ajax. it should show your file with the data its been send to. also it shows the response

Comment: Please read [mcve] with special attention to the minimal part (keeping in mind Dorvalla's comment above for context)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a answer as such at this stage, but a few points of note that might help reach an answer:

- the code that displays the "Submit failed" message is actually in the success response section. It shows the message if there is a non-null, non-empty string returned by the AJAX call. It would help if the string was output to help debug if it's an actual failure to save the data, or not
- following on from the above, check if the data submitted has been saved or not - that will help establish what is actually happening
- In the second form, we can see the URL (urlFormUpdateWithNotice) but in the first we can't, so it's hard to tell if that is a problem (e.g. there could be a typo in the URL)

Ideally you need to include as much detail as possible, including any critical data, so that diagnosing the problem is easier and quicker.

In any case the best place to start is to see what **text** is in `success: function (text) {...` and take it from there.